# Add files to dist when building library using vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I want to add a folder with some JSON files within the `dist` folder when building my own library using vue-cli.

I run the following command to build the library:

`vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.js`.

I have tried to add the folder within the `public` folder, but it doesn't work when building library.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cp` command

```
   vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.js && cp -R public/* dist
```

Comment: It shows the following error: `'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: I solved it using `xcopy` instead of `cp`. Thanks for your help.